# One table instead of two with some empty columns

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to figure out if I should create 2 different tables for my problem or if I could just use one.

I've got the following two scenarios and data to store:

```
- Date
- Time (Occasionally)
- Description

- Title
- Description
- Date (started)
- Date (ended) (Occasionally)
```

The Occasionally fields are not required all the time. I was thinking since most of the fields are the same I could maybe use 1 table instead of 2. (Maybe it is better pefromance wise and cleaner)

Comment: Please add more detail - what are the tables for? Do you see a performance issue? If you do not understand how to do ER modelling, please read about it first.

Comment: If you don't have a specific reason (performance or otherwise) right now - go with the simpler option. A few mostly empty columns in the DB are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Second scenario)  Let `NULL` indicate "not ended or not-yet ended".  And declare it

```
started DATE NOT NULL,
ended   DATE     NULL
```

Exercise left to reader:  Do something similar in first scenario.

Or you could think of `NULL` as meaning "empty".

Note:  Test via `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`, not `=`, etc.